# Help with looping through groups of radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

I am having an issue looping through several groups of radio buttons.

So my goal is to loop through and list several groups of shipping options for various products. First I loop through the number of items which need to be shipped alone, then I loop through the shipping rates.

What I want is each group to be able to have 1 selection and pass along the params for use in the controller. I need the ability to iterate or count the ss_ship_info so that each name/value will be different params. I have tried both `ss_ship_info#{@counter}` and `ss_ship_info[@counter]` (this one has really unexpected results, if I have 3 items. The first two act like a single group but the third seems to be an individual group.) Does anyone know a solution for my problem or at the very least could point me in the direction of a guide relating to the subject?

```
<% @sscount.times do %>  #First Loop 
   <% for rate in @ups_ss_rates[@counter] %> # Second Loop 
      <label> 
         <%= radio_button_tag('ss_ship_info_#{@counter}', rate[0]) %> 
         <%= rate[0] %> - <span class="money"><b><%= sub_number_to_currency((rate[1])) %></b></span> 
      </label> 
    <% end %> 
   <% @counter += 1 %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where is `@counter` getting set?

Comment: Just right outside the first loop. It is intialized to 0. My issue seems to be with the radio_button_tag line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I could iterate my groups of radio buttons by doing this:

<%= radio_button_tag("ss_ship_info_" + @counter.to_s, rate[0]) %>

Hope this helps anyone who runs across this issue.